# Decay of particle question

Tags: particle-physics, standard-model, feynman-diagrams

How would you draw the diagram for the $D$ meson decay mode:

$$ D^- \rightarrow K^+ + \pi^- + \pi^- $$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The $\bar{c}$ initial quark emits a $W^-$ and becomes an $\bar{s}$ quark in the final state. The $W^-$ decays into a $\bar{u}d$ pair. One of the quarks emits a neutral gauge boson (gluon/$Z$/photon), which decays into a $u\bar{u}$ pair.

The $K^+$ forms from the $\bar{s}$ and the $u$ from the neutral gauge boson. Then you have $\bar{u}d$ from the $W^-$ decay, the $\bar{u}$ from the neutral gauge boson, and the original $d$ from the D meson, which can be arranged into two $\pi^-$.